# R, SQL problems debugging a package, debug(.Call)

Tags: sql-server, r, debugging

I am trying to debug an error that I think is in a pacakge.  While I am stepping through the code with the debugger there is a section of code that produces the error I am getting.

```
if (fetch == FALSE | nrow(data) < 1) {
        stat <- .Call("RODBCExecute", attr(channel, "handle_ptr"), 
            data, as.integer(rows_at_time))
        if (stat == -1L) {
            if (errors) {
                stop(paste0(RODBC::odbcGetErrMsg(channel), collapse = "\n"))
            }
            else {
                return(stat)
            }
        }
```

`.Call()` sets stat = -1  and this produces the error.   I tried to use `debug(.Call)` but this is not working.  From what I understand from searching online is that the `.Call()` uses compiled C/C++ code.  Is there anyway to debug this code any farther?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct: .Call("thisCFunction",...) calls a C/C++ function, loaded in by the package from the .so file, that is called thisCFunction in it's C++ declaration.

I would *not* try to debug this; you would have to go through the C++ source code by hand to figure out exactly what's happening, which would require a firm understanding of not only general C/C++ but also R's API (and the author's style of programming). Not trying to be rude, but I would guess if you are unfamiliar with .Call and what it does, you're probably unfamiliar with R's API.

An easier first step would be to track down exactly what is being supplied to this function and try to figure out why it's not what RODBCExecute expects. Given that the authors have written an error message, I would check to see if that error message helps point out the issue. My guess is that the real error occurred much earlier and this results in providing invalid arguments to RODBCExecute.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I looked at what was being supplied to the function.  As far as I can tell for `attr(channel, "handle_ptr")` , `channel` is the name of the connection to SQL and `"handle_ptr"` is the name of the handle for ODBC, `data` is the data frame I supplied to `sqlExecute()` from the `RODBCext` package, and `rows_at_time` has a default setting for the function.  From the results of the error, something is wrong with the cursor state.   I am not sure if the cursor state has to do with my data frame are with something in SQL?

Comment: sql is not my wheelhouse, so I will be of no help on that. I would try a search for the exact error message produced. But my guess is that there's nothing wrong with the C++ function RODBCExecute.